# SQL Incrementing Value for non existent row

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a table with a field: UserProjectNumber, this is just a int field that needs to increment by one everytime. I currently increment this number using the following INSERT statement. This works perfectly as long as there is already a record in the table for this user. If this is the first time the statement is run it fails because it can't add 1 to NULL

```
INSERT INTO UserProject (UserID, UserProjectName,  UserProjectNumber) 
VALUES  (2, 'Test', CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(UserProjectNumber) FROM UserProject WHERE UserID=2)= NULL THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT MAX(UserProjectNumber) FROM UserProject WHERE UserID=2)+1 END )
```

I am using MS SQL Server 2012. Can anybody suggest a way to resolve this? Perhaps somehow converting the NULL to a 0?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that using an `IDENTITY` column is unacceptable?

Comment: @HABO - Still gives the same Error about insert a NULL value. The Identity column is the PK for this table. The User can only ever have 6 projects - Number 1 to Number 6 - the identity number would not be viable on this occasion as it could be in the millions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayhaps this will do:

```
    declare @UserProject as Table
      ( UserProjectId Int Identity, UserId Int, UserProjectName VarChar(32), UserProjectNumber Int );

    insert into @UserProject ( UserId, UserProjectName, UserProjectNumber ) values
      ( 2, 'Test', ( select IsNull( Max( UserProjectNumber ), 0 ) + 1 from @UserProject where UserId = 2 ) );
    insert into @UserProject ( UserId, UserProjectName, UserProjectNumber ) values
      ( 2, 'Alpha', ( select IsNull( Max( UserProjectNumber ), 0 ) + 1 from @UserProject where UserId = 2 ) );
    insert into @UserProject ( UserId, UserProjectName, UserProjectNumber ) values
      ( 1, 'Aleph', ( select IsNull( Max( UserProjectNumber ), 0 ) + 1 from @UserProject where UserId = 1 ) );
    insert into @UserProject ( UserId, UserProjectName, UserProjectNumber ) values
      ( 2, 'Beta', ( select IsNull( Max( UserProjectNumber ), 0 ) + 1 from @UserProject where UserId = 2 ) );
    insert into @UserProject ( UserId, UserProjectName, UserProjectNumber ) values
      ( 1, 'Beth', ( select IsNull( Max( UserProjectNumber ), 0 ) + 1 from @UserProject where UserId = 1 ) );

    select *
      from @UserProject
      order by UserId, UserProjectNumber;
```

Maintenance of the `UserProjectNumber` column becomes problematic when users are allowed to delete projects. Should the numbers remain dense? Should new projects reuse old numbers?

If the purpose of adding the `UserProjectNumber` is solely for display, then it probably makes more sense to either generate a number on the fly using `Row_Number() over ( partition by UserId order by UserProjectName )` or leave it up to the application.

If the purpose is to enforce the limit of six projects per user then a constraint using `Count()`, or a trigger, may be a better choice.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() Is EXACTLY what I was looking for - I didn't even know that existed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO UserProject (UserID, UserProjectName,  UserProjectNumber) 
VALUES  (2, 'Test', ISNULL((SELECT MAX(UserProjectNumber) FROM UserProject WHERE UserID=2),0)+1)
```

Comment: GIVES ERROR: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserProjectDeadline', table 'dbo.UserProject'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: @James Supply a value for *UserProjectDeadline* (or add a DEFAULT constraint). Note that it's *not* one of the fields already specified.

Comment: @user2246674 it already has default constraint of 1 but I am Inserting the record via asp.net so It would require to seperate statements which i am trying to avoid